# How to fix "org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.RequestContext must be in the Singleton scope"

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly, hk2

I'd like to implement a simple REST-API with Jersey and grizzly. After beeing stuck in dependency-hell for a while, I ended up with an exception and I have no idea how to handle/interpret:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The implementation class org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext must be in the Singleton scope
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.checkConfiguration(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1713)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.addConfiguration(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2108)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DynamicConfigurationImpl.commit(DynamicConfigurationImpl.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(ServiceLocatorUtilities.java:166)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.<init>(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:65)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.<init>(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:38)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory$Hk2InjectionManagerStrategy$1.createInjectionManager(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.create(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:69)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.<init>(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:310)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:93)
    at src.main.java.myApplication.main(myApplication.java:141)
```

The exception happens in my main-class on creating the http-server:

```
URI uri= URI.create("http://localhost:8080");       
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
config.register(myAPI.class);

HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, config);
try{
    server.start();
} catch( IOException e ) {
    logger.error("Exception on starting HTTP-Server.", e);
}
```

The myAPI.java is nothing special yet and also not important for the problem here, I think. Nevertheless, it looks like this:

```
public class myAPI extends ResourceConfig{
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public myAPI(){
    }

    @Path("/hello")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response foo() {
        ObjectNode json = mapper.createObjectNode();
        json.put("status", "ok");
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(json).build();
    }    
}
```

My classpath contains the following huge amount of libraries:

```
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
grizzly-framework-3.0.0.jar
grizzly-http-server-3.0.0.jar
grizzly-http-server-multipart-3.0.0.jar
hk2-api-2.6.1.jar
hk2-locator-2.6.1.jar
hk2-utils-2.6.1.jar
jakarta.annotation-api-2.0.0.jar
jakarta.inject-api-2.0.0.jar
jakarta.ws.rs-api-3.0.0.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
jersey-common-3.0.2.jar
jersey-container-grizzly2-http-3.0.2.jar
jersey-guava-2.22.1.jar
jersey-hk2-3.0.2.jar
jersey-server-3.0.2.jar
org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.3.jar
jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
jackson-core-2.9.4.jar
jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar
-
httpclient-4.5.13.jar
httpcore-4.4.14.jar
httpmime-4.5.13.jar
log4j-api-2.14.1.jar
log4j-core-2.14.1.jar
```

The libraries below the dash are needed for another module (http-client) inside my application. I know that I probably could have used some of the libraries there, which I also use for the http-server, but I couldn't get it to work otherwise. But that's not the focus here, only when this is responsible for some kind of collusions due to multiple implementations?! After the long trail-and-error in dependency-hell, it is also possible that some libraries are even not needed.

So the core-question is, how I can put the RequestContext into the singleton-scope?! I haven't even declared a RequestContext anywhere. Do I have to add it in some way?

Side-fact: I also tried the same with the Jersey-JdkHttpServerFactory and ended up with the same error.

Comment: _" After beeing stuck in dependency-hell for a while"_ - I highly suggest you use/learn a dependency manager like Maven. Nobody is going to be able to test out your problem unless they download all the jars you are using. And I doubt anybody is going to do that. It would be easier if you just had a list of Maven dependencies. Not for just others, but using Maven will definitely make your life a lot easier. I've never seen the problem you are facing, but I wouldn't doubt that it might have something to do with a dependency problem.

Comment: I definitely know that and generelly prefer Maven. Unfortunately the project must be realized for internal reasons without Maven...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not your solution, but for other people that run to the same problem. In my case, this was caused because of a conflict between libraries.

I have a Dynamic Web Project using Tomcat 8.5 (with the javax libraries for jersey). I created another project, but for Tomcat 10. I copied all the files in the src folder, added the Tomcat 10 libraries (jakarta) and updated the imports from "javax.ws.rs..." to "jakarta.ws.rs..." but got that error.

When cleaning the jar files in the lib folder, the problem disappeared.